# Disable Web Security on Spring Security 6

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am looking for a way that I would be able to disable spring security for a specific profile, "development" for example. This question has been asked before but recently with Spring Security 6 coming out there have been a lot of changes and I wonder how that is possible. This is my current security configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true
)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private final AuthJwtEntrypoint unauthorizedHandler;
    private final FilterChainExceptionHandler filterChainExceptionHandler;

    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService,
                             AuthJwtEntrypoint unauthorizedHandler,
                             FilterChainExceptionHandler filterChainExceptionHandler) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
        this.filterChainExceptionHandler = filterChainExceptionHandler;
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/country/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
        httpSecurity.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(filterChainExceptionHandler, LogoutFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8080", "http://127.0.0.1:8080"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "content-type"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

I want to be allowed to send requests without having jwt token or having a special role (for method protection security), how can I achieve that?

## Edit

What I have tried :

```
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        if (Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles()).contains("development")) {
            // In the development profile, permit all requests.
            httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                    auth.anyRequest().permitAll()
            );
        } else {
            // In other profiles, use your regular security configuration.
            httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/api/country/**").permitAll()
                            // ... (other authorization rules)
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );
        }

        httpSecurity.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(filterChainExceptionHandler, LogoutFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

This works fine, but I still get access denied on methods that are annotated with @Secured.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, annotate the production profile with `@Profile("!development")`, this will make sure that this configuration will only execute if you didn't set your spring boot application profile to development.
Now you are ready to create a class for your development profile!

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("development")
public class UnsecuredWebConfig {

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private final AuthJwtEntrypoint unauthorizedHandler;
    private final FilterChainExceptionHandler filterChainExceptionHandler;

    public UnsecuredWebConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService,
                              AuthJwtEntrypoint unauthorizedHandler,
                              FilterChainExceptionHandler filterChainExceptionHandler) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
        this.filterChainExceptionHandler = filterChainExceptionHandler;
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                auth.anyRequest().permitAll()
        );
        httpSecurity.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(filterChainExceptionHandler, LogoutFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

}
```

This will help you to test your api's without having special roles or sending jwt token.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(
    securedEnabled = true
)
@Profile("development")
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    ...
}
```

With in application.properties

```
# As you can choose whatever
spring.profiles.active=production
```

This could disable all the written configuration in WebSecurityConfig class then you can do some without any configurations in development server.

Comment: Are your sure? What about the real configuration? You have to add a profile for the real configuration, too?